# Getting array from generated php document

Tags: php

I am currently generating `config.php` file that has an array w user details in it ,but I have a problem with getting the array back out to be used on the page, the `config.php` looks like this

```
Array
(
 [DBLocation] => localhost
 [DBName] => name
 [DBUsername] => name
 [DBPassword] => 123456
)
```

How can I use this array later?

Comment: echo $array['DBLocation'] ; this will return localhost !

Comment: No way. it's simple store like string  or you can say plain-text

Comment: just store as dblocation=localhost,\n dbname=databasename

Answer (score 3):

Convert your `config.php` file like this:-

```
<?php
  $arr = Array
  (
     'DBLocation' => 'localhost',
     'DBName' => 'TAK14_Ostermann',
     'DBUsername' => 'TAK14_Ostermann',
     'DBPassword' => '123456'
  );
?>
```

Now include this file into others with code:-`include 'config.php'` and use `$arr` variable.

***Note:***

Better to do a complete configuration code in the file (`config.php`) itself and create a database connection object. Now use that object by including the file. ***It will remove db-connection code redundancy in each page.***

Answer (score 0):

If the array you posted is the exact content of the `config.php` file you are not generating it in the right way.

The posted "array" is what [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) outputs. As the documentation says:

> `print_r` — Prints human-readable information about a variable.

The key here is "human-readable". The purpose of `print_r()` is to produce an output that is easy to read and understand by the programmer. It is a debug function, not meant to be used in the production code.

The function you need to generate the content of `config.php` is [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). It produces correct PHP code and it is specifically crafted for this purpose.

Assuming your configuration data is stored in the `$config` array, the code that generates `config.php` should be like this:

```
file_put_contents('config.php', '<?php return '.var_export($config, TRUE).";\n");
```

The generated `config.php` file will look like this:

```
<?php return array (
  'DBLocation' => 'localhost',
  'DBName' => 'name',
  'DBUsername' => 'name',
  'DBPassword' => '123456',
);
```

In order to load the configuration use [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

```
$config = include 'config.php';
```